# Teamcity checkout uses older SVN

Tags: svn, teamcity, build-automation

I have Teamcity ( 7.3 ) checkout the code for me from SVN.  It will put it in some temp path which is good

```
[12:46:10]: Updating sources
[12:46:10]:  [Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Checkout directory is empty or doesn't exist
[12:46:10]:  [Updating sources] Cleaning C:\_app\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a29b6ff3968e4c7a
[12:46:10]:  [Updating sources] VCS Root: MyAppBuild
```

The problem is when I update the version file with the new version ( running build # ) and execute SVN commit on it from my Nant script SVN will throw an error.

```
[12:46:20]:  [NAnt output]      [exec] svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
[12:46:20]:  [NAnt output]      [exec] svn: E155036: Working copy 'C:\_app\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a29b6ff3968e4c7a\MyApp' is too old (format 10, created by Subversion 1.6)
```

Which is unexpected, the only svn on the computer is version 1.7.5  Can anybody explain how Teamcity was able to checkout apparently using 1.6 svn version ?  I searched the Teamcity directories for svn.exe without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, you can choose which version Teamcity should use when doing the checkout.  Under the VCS root settings in the drop down list ( 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 ( Default ), 1.7 )

Checkout on agent settings 
  Working copy format: 1.7